# Weblogic: Setting character encoding with WLST

Tags: weblogic, charset

We are using WLST (Weblogic Scripting Language) to setup our Weblogic domains and managed servers. Now we would like to enforce the usage of UTF-8 character encoding globally.

What I found here is the method..

```
setDefaultCharCodeset(String codeset)
```

..which seems to do exactly what we need: it sets the default charset to some specified value. Now, this method is defined on the Weblogic MBean - and is accessible in WLST through the use of cmo (the *"Current Management Object"*).

So, for example: if we have a Server named `Foo` we can do a

```
cd('/Servers/Foo')
cmo.setDefaultCharCodeset('UTF-8')
```

My question is:
Do the properties of the MBeans/Management Objects somehow propagate through a hierarchy?

What happens if I set the charset at root level?

```
cd('/')
cmo.setDefaultCharCodeset('UTF-8')
```

Will this enforce global usage of UTF-8?
Or do we need to set it specifially for each managed server?

---

*P.S. We are using WLS 12c on Solaris 11 to run a variety of J2EE applications with Oracle back ends.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code above is not right:

The `defaultCharCodeset` is a field of the IIOP MBean, not the Server MBean (and also not the the domain MBean). The IIOP MBean on the other hand is a child of ther Server MBean.

I found it like this: `find('defaultCharCodeset')`, which gave me nice output as to where this field shows up in WLST config tree:

```
/Servers/AdminServer/IIOP/AdminServer          DefaultCharCodeset                                 US-ASCII
/Servers/app_1/IIOP/app_1                      DefaultCharCodeset                                 US-ASCII
...
(app_1 is a managed server we defined)
```

So the right way to do this seems to be:

```
cd('/Servers/app_1/IIOP/app_1)
cmo.setDefaultCharCodeset('UTF-8')
...
```